# Why do I get 0 when this python code is executed?

Tags: python, arrays

The python code, given in a lab for a class I'm in when executed through pycharm, ouputs 0. However, upon looking at the code, it should be 1. Why is it 0?

```
X = 4
C = 0
while X > 0:
    if X % 2 == 0:
        C = C + 1
    else:
        C = C - 1
    X = X - 1
print(C)
```

Comment: Why should it be 1?

Comment: (Also, you don't get 0 when you run this. You get a SyntaxError.)

Comment: Loop should execute 4 times. Increment twice, decrement twice. Seems right to me.

Comment: Print `c` values in-between and you will understand how things are working.

Comment: if it outputs 0 when you run it, then it SHOULD be zero, and theres something youre assuming thats off about the code.

Comment: Printing values inside the loop usually helps you visualize what is happening. Here is another useful tool to visualize code execution - http://pythontutor.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code is fine. Your X will go from 4 to 1 and on X = 0, the program will leave the loop. Printing X-C for each iteration gives the values:

```
X-C
4-1
3-0
2-1
1-0
```

If you want it to go till 0, make the condition as:

```
 while X >= 0:
```

Answer (score 0):

The loop executes 4 times: When X = 4, C = 1; when X = 3, C = 0; when X = 2, C = 1; when X = 1, C = 0.